# Razor can't detect end of section

Tags: c#, html, c#-4.0, razor, razor-2

I have some trouble with razor sections.

```html
@section tools {
<div class="btn-group"">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Update every <span id="update_time_label" class="label label-info">10 s.</span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" onclick="return SelfAction.setUpdateTime(1)">1 s.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="return SelfAction.setUpdateTime(5)">5 s.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="return SelfAction.setUpdateTime(10)">10 s.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="return SelfAction.setUpdateTime(30)">30 s.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="return SelfAction.setUpdateTime(60)">60 s.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="return SelfAction.setUpdateTime(120)">120 s.</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<button class="btn" onclick="return SelfAction.loadNewItemsNow()">Update now</button>
} <-- Can't detect
```

As you see in the code, it does not detect the closing bracket. I'm now learning C# and MVC4 and can't find any solution. I don't want to use viewbag for this big HTML block. Maybe there is some specific closing tag for big HTML blocks? Something like `@sectionStart` and `@sectionEnd`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the second " at the end of `<div class="btn-group"">` and see if that helps. The Razor engine is VERY finicky, and something stupid like that could cause it to continue to look for a string, and since everything else matches up, the closing `}` would be inside a string.

Comment: Wow... I feel so dumb now... Thank you. As soon 9 minutes passes I will accept your answer.

Comment: Not a problem. I'm glad I can help. Like I said, Razor can be a pain to work with, but it is very powerful.

Comment: Well, that true. But after PHP and Smarty it feels like something new and amazing.